# Firestore - Single test user causes 50K+ reads

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've recently been experimenting with some Firestore security rules and, as a single user, have found myself causing over 100K denies within the first hour of setting up said rules.

I have also noticed that in the last 30 days, my single use has incurred almost 1M allows, I guess I would only expect to hit around 1 - 5K in a month from my average usage.

I would obviously expect to incur a higher number of denies within my rules testing period, but why is the number so high? I only reached 916 total DB reads in the last 7 days, but have somehow also blown out my usage limits, so now I can't access any collections.

My ruleset, I intend to refine this as I was cut off testing it properly, so I'm aware of its bugs.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /users/{userID} {
      allow update, write, delete: if request.auth != null && 
        request.auth.uid == userID;
      allow read, create: if request.auth != null;
      match /public_trips/{tripID}/{likedBy} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null &&
            request.resource.data.likedBy == likedBy;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: image of firestore dashboard, 24 hour period, 7.7K allows, 106K denies, 608 errors]

[image: image of firestore dashboard, 30 day period, 862K allows, 642 denies, 608 errors]

The image below is what I'd expect my usage to look like (and what it actually reports) based on how much testing I perform.

[image: image of firestore dashboard 916 reads, 71 writes]

[image: image of google quota dashboard, daily operations, 0.05M/0.05M ops used, 100%]

The above was not expected.

As this quota reads, I have exceeded my read limit of 50K for the day, but as I said firestore only reports >1K?

**TL; DR**

Why have I incurred 100K+ denies from a single user?

Is this because my rules are wonky, or because my app is inefficient?

Comment: Are you running automated tests against the production Firestore instance? Or are you only testing it manually?

Comment: The tests aren't automated, and the only existing firestore instance is dev, so only I have access to it. Most of my tests are the dev application accessing the API, but some from the cloud firestore test playground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

Your app is inefficient.

---

Your rules are not accessing other documents in the database, and thus, cannot be causing additional reads. So the reason you're getting so many denies is that you're making that many requests. Most likely, this is because the way you have modeled your data is not very efficient.

For example, in the case of a restaurant app, you might be getting all review documents to compute the average rating and the total number of ratings. Instead, you should store those as fields in the restaurant document and have a Cloud Function update them when a review is added, updated, or deleted.

Comment: I'm gonna have a look around my app to see if there's anything that stands out, as you're most probably right.  I suspect a resource hungry stream listening for too long. I'll get back to you tomorrow, as this is when my quota limit will reset.

Comment: You can try using [Firebase Emulators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite). They allow you to use local versions of Firebase services and have no quota limits.

Comment: Okay sure, I'd noticed them before assuming they were bound by the same limits. Thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: Could I just ask if there's anything you see wrong with those rules?  Where it states `/public_trips/{tripID}/{likedBy}`, the `{likedBy}` is supposed to represent a field under the specific `{tripID}` document.  Is this an appropriate way to access a document's variable?

Comment: @Jake no. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: Yep, I found a workaround since then.

Comment: @Jake If this answer has solved your question, please consider accepting it.